# Air conditioner not blowing air

Tags: air-conditioning

I have a LG air conditioner that i can find it online, not sure why. when i turn it on, there is no air blowing. not sure if it helps but the model number is hs-0964f73. not sure why but i cant seem to find it online.

Comment: some air conditioners need some time to start blowing air. They may take up to 5 minutes to start blowing. Have you tried waiting for a bit?

Answer (score 1):

The LG split unit I installed had a micro switch in the cover that stops the fan motor while the cover is open, make sure the filters are seated and the covers closed. If the fan still won't start you will need to check the control board for error codes. It's been a few years but I remember that switch was a pain.  Added from memory there are a couple of things that will stop the unit from working, dirty filters high liquid level (drain plugged) filters not seated door not fully closing. I am sure there were more there should be an owners manual it has a troubleshooting guide with quite a few pages of problems and solutions in the back but it has been a while.

Comment: how to check the control board for error codes?

Comment: The LED's were on a small control board you have to look at those. I can't remember for sure but think the remote will also provide the error. The control board is just inside the cover. Of the inside unit.

Comment: You might want to start by turning off the circuit breaker, waiting a minute, and restarting. That can clear some codes and ambiguous states.